# Replace value in column based on value in another column

Tags: pandas, replace

I have a dataframe with 3240 rows and 3 columns. Column Block represents the block in which values in column A and B appeared. Unique number of blocks is 6 but they are repeating in sequence throughout whole dataframe from 1-6. Values in `column A` are repeating themselves in the sequences of `exact order` from `1-10` throughout the whole dataframe (blocks). Values in `column B` exist from `a-j (n = 10)`, but they repeating themselves in `random order` in sequences from `a-j`, so they are never duplicated within the Block.

So in each of 6 Blocks, values in column A (1-10) repeat themselves in exact order from 1-10, while In column B, values (a-j) repeat themselves in random order.

Df looks like this:

```
  Block      A    B    ID

    1        1    a    XY
    1        2    b    XY
    1        3    c    XY
    1        4    d    XY
    1        5    e    XY
    1        6    f    XY
    1        7    g    XY
    1        8    h    XY
    1        9    i    XY
    1        10   j    XY
....
    6        1    d    XY
... 
    6        6    j    XY
....
    1        1    g    XX
    1        2    a    XX
```

Throughout dataframe i would like to replace all values in column B based on corresponding value in column A for each separate Block. Logic would be to replace values in column B based on values in column A by this pattern 1=6, 2=7, 3=8, 4=9, 5=10.
Result would look like this:

```
  Block      A    B    ID

    1        1    f    XY
    1        2    g    XY
    1        3    h    XY
    1        4    i    XY
    1        5    j    XY
    1        6    a    XY
    1        7    b    XY
    1        8    c    XY
    1        9    d    XY
    1        10   e    XY
....
    6        1    j    XY
...
    6        6    d    XY
....
    1        1    g    XX
    1        2    a    XX
```

What would be an efficient to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to identify the block of `5` within each block of `10` and swap them. This is my solution:

```
df['B'] = (df.assign(blk_5 = (np.arange(len(df))//5+1) % 2,
                     blk_10 = np.arange(len(df)) // 10
                    )
             .sort_values(['Block','blk_10','blk_5'])
             ['B'].values
          )
```

Comment: Sorry for incomprehensible explanation.  There are 6 Blocks and i want to perform the logic explained above for each block separately. So all values in column B would be replaced based on corresponding value in column A for each block. If A=1,6 and B=a,f then i would need A=1,6 and B=f,a. I hope this helps

Comment: I think i detect the problem. I skipped one important thing: column of subject ID. Each subject underwend over all 6 blocks. There were 54 subjects in total so I need to distinstinct betweel all 54 subjcets and reassign the values within each block for each subject.

Comment: Blocks are repeating itself for each subject from 1-6. So when subject's data ends with last value in block 6, another subject's data starts in block 1.